# How do I load QMovie within QtDesigner?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt-designer

I need to be load QMovie in QtDesigner. I noticed that a lot of classes are not accessible from QtDesigner. I usually design in QtDesigner and I just load the ui file directly in my code. This way I never had to worry about implementing the GUI itself in code.
Is there a way I can do this without having to edit my code ?

So in summation I want to add QMovie to a horizontal layout in my main window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QMovie` is not a widget, so it makes no sense to add it to as layout.

You probably want a `QLabel`, which has a [setMovie](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#setMovie) method for dispalying animated images. But note that a `QMovie` cannot play videos - if you want that functionality, you will have to use a [Phonon.VideoWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/phonon-videowidget.html), rather than a `QLabel`.